# Recognizing rectangles in template images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rectangles

So I'm trying to recognize an region that's already been defined by a bounding box. Example: [image: Bowser]

Some of the areas within these rectangles in these images are white and some are black, and most of them are completely different sizes. The only common characteristic between these images is the red rectangle: [image]

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a randomly generated meme bot that places a random source image in the region defined by these rectangles. I have tons of these images already with predefined areas with these red rectangles for use. I want to automate the process somehow, currently every resize shape and offset has to be defined for each template. So what I need to do is recognize the area within the rectangle and have it return the defined resize shape and offset needed to place the source image.

How should I go about this? Should I use something in OpenCV or am I going to have to train a CNN? Just really looking for a push in the right direction because I'm pretty lost as to the best approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think OpenCV can do it. Below is a short example of the steps for what you need. Read the comments in the code for more details.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")

#STEP1: get only red color (or the bounding box color) in the image
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# define range of red color in HSV
lower_red = np.array([0,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([0,255,255])
# Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
red_only = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

#STEP2: find contour
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(red_only,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#max contour in the image is the box you want
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
sorted_areas = np.sort(areas)
cnt=contours[areas.index(sorted_areas[-1])]
r = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(img,(r[0],r[1]),(r[0]+r[2],r[1]+r[3]),(0,255,0),3)

cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.imshow("red_only",red_only)
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]